# React app on Aws Amplify receives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to access to Elastic Beanstalk Springboot app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I have created a react app that connects to a Springboot API on an Elastic Beanstalk.

I'm successfully connecting to my Beanstalk API from my local machine, but my React app (deployed with Amplify) receives a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
What could be the reason?

The Url I'm using to connect from the React app is: http://ec2-18-133-11-111.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (I modified the ip for privacy reasons)

**EDIT** For some reason, The api call is being redirected to https. I think this is the reason. How do I prevent this?

Here is how the sg inbound is configured:
[image]
What else do I need to do?

Comment: Do you try to connect using http or https ?  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is usually a client side error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried both.

Comment: @Marcin For some reason, The api call is being redirected to https. I think this is the reason. How do I prevent this?

Comment: What is redirecting it? Have you setup your ELB on EB to redirect HTTP to https? Or is your app doing this?

Comment: I just see in the browser dev tools that the request is being done to https, while I set it to http

Comment: Maybe you have some browser extensions that redirect it, such as "always https" or similar? Did you test with other browser?

Comment: Actually in Firefox the request is done to http, which is correct, but still it receives the error. If I click on the url, I do get the results from the api.